# Prove $|a+b-1| > |ab|$ where $|a|>1$, $a \in \mathbb{C}$, and $b \in (0,1)$.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, normed-spaces, absolute-value

It may be stupid but I really do not know how to prove it.

> Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$, and $|a| >1$. Let $b \in (0,1)$. Prove
>   \begin{equation*}
> |a+b-1| > |ab|.
> \end{equation*}

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think there is a typo - where is $\lambda$ in that equation?

Comment: If $ a= b = 1/2$ it does not work.

Comment: @csch2 Yes, it is a typo. Thanks! I have fixed it.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah, Sorry.. I need $|a| > 1$, and a typo has been fixed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM
$$|a|^2+1> 2|a|\geq 2\Re(a).$$
Therefore
$$|a|^2-1> 2\big(\Re(a)-1\big).$$
Since $|a|>1$, $|a|^2-1>0$.  Thus
$$(1+b)\big(|a|^2-1\big)>|a|^2-1>2\big(\Re(a)-1\big).$$
Thus
$$(1-b^2)\big(|a|^2-1\big)=(1-b)\Big((1+b)\big(|a|^2-1\big)\Big)>2(1-b)\big(\Re(a)-1\big).$$
Hence
$$|a|^2+b^2-|a|^2b^2-1>2\Re(a)+2b-2-2\Re(a)b,$$
or
$$|a|^2+b^2+1-2b-2\Re(a)-2\Re(a)b>|a|^2b^2.$$
That is, 
$$|a+b-1|^2>|a|^2b^2=|ab|^2.$$

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=x+iy$ with $x,y$ real, $x^2+y^2-1>0$ and $0<b<1$. Then $$|a+b-1|>|ab|$$ $$\Leftrightarrow (x+b-1)^2+y^2>b^2(x^2+y^2)~{\rm (by~raising~to~square)}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (1-b)[(x-1)^2+b(x^2+y^2-1)+y^2]>0~({\rm by~rearranging}),$$ whence the result.